# Unable to take snapshot with save command in redis

Tags: php, redis

I have redis installed on vps server and to os is centos. I am accessing the server using ssh (via Putty from windows).

problem i am facing is when i hit save command my database is not taking the snapshot. My dump.rdb file is empty even after i hit save command on cli. I tired changing the default path of the dump.rdb yet it dint work.

also all the keys in the database get deleted automatically

Will be thankful if anyone can help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check If there is needed permission to write the file. What is the command you use? SAVE or BGSAVE?